# Gmail account possible hack

Tags: gmail

Today my girlfriend received an email from Gmail saying:

> Someone recently tried to sign in to your Google Account, @gmail.com. We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this was a hijacker trying to access your account. Please review the details of the sign-in attempt:
>
> May 9, 2012 12:28pm GMT
> IP Address: 79.108.244.5
> Location: Valencia, Spain
>
> If you do not recognize this sign-in attempt, someone else might be trying to access your account. You should sign in to your account and reset your password immediately. Find out how at http://support.google.com/accounts?p=reset_pw
>
> Sincerely,
> The Google Accounts Team

I have changed the password.

Is there anything else we can do?

She has an iPhone; could there be a security issue with this?

Facebook and Instagram are her most used apps.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anything else we can do?

Yes. You can make the email ID more secure by turning on two-step authentication. [More details here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/make-your-email-hacker-proof.html). It might be a bit bothersome for your girlfriend at first. But it might bother her more if her account gets hacked.

Comment: turned on 2 step for her, im going to doit for my accounts too  , thanks for youre reply

Answer (score 1):

> To help minimize damage from unauthorized access to your account,
>   Google alerts you when someone signs in to your account from an
>   unusual location. Their goal is to help you secure your account
>   quickly if an unauthorized person has access to it. This especially
>   also happens if you sign in to your account from an unusual location
>   and even make a wrong password login attempt. They alert you about
>   sign-ins that are from locations and devices that they previously have
>   not seen signing in to your account and ask you if it was you who
>   signed in from those locations or devices.  To help you determine if
>   it was you, they show you the information they have about the
>   suspicious sign-in event(s) including the IP address, its location,
>   the domain associated with the IP address and the time at which it
>   accessed your account.

If the location was familiar, then do not worry. If not, I advise that you change your password, update your account recovery options and run a virus scan on your computer.

More info is available here: [Suspicious sign-in alerts](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1144110)

Answer (score 0):

Changing your password is a great first step, but those password changes won't affect authenticated applications using your Google Account.

You should do the following:

- [2-step authentication](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthConfig)
- [Application passwords](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en) for an additional protection
- go to [My Account](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en) and verify that each of the applications listed at the top are recognized and authorized. Remove any that aren't.

Comment: im not sure where on the accounts page you are talking about :(

Comment: At the top of the accounts page is a list of applications that have been authorized to use the account. If you don't see any, then you don't need to worry regarding this specific incident.

Answer (score -2):

If you try to log in with a proxy server, you generally get this sort of notification. This might be why you're seeing it.

Comment: Please try to use proper English. It would help make your answer understandable.